# Video lag in vlc and totem

Tags: ati, vlc, video-player, media, totem

I have an ATI video card in my Dell inspiron, I'm getting some offset of audio/video (out of sync) wondering if I can do upgrades to solve this

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried different options, different media players, but had got a dual boot with windows working properly so I've resorted to using windows for media. I'll keep attempting different settings, though had to step away from it for now, too frustrating to have 2 sec. delay of audio. Too confused that it wouldn't work properly.

Comment: Also it may be something to do with VGA output, though again windows works properly with my aquos screen and same problem occurs on laptop monitor. It's odd.

Comment: Also should add I've used windows for years, Linux is newer to me, a project of sorts, so I may not have the right thinking on certain settings, but I would think it would work without much tweaking, so I'm open to any opinions. I've had accelerator going aswell

Answer (score 1):

User,

Why do you think it could be your video driver?
May be is render mode, that use in your VLC...

You can try this:

Open VLC, then press Ctrl + P (to get in preference)
It open another window. Go to video item (at your left) and see Output.

There is a lot of render mode, I use OpenGL, but you can select another to try get better performance.

Is this issue with all your videos?

Take Care.

Comment: The users says it's not only affecting VLC but also Totem. And you shouldn't change the default setting for video output, rather enable video acceleration via "Input & Codecs".